# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined after using Onpress navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am getting error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined" when I am using navigation inside const function. Is it due to to undefined props. I am still beginner to intermediate level in React Native. Here is my code:

```js
const Home = (props) => {
  if (props.authState === 'signedIn')
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.submitButton4}
          title="Create Profile"
          color="orange"
          fontSize="18"
          padding="20"
          height="hp('7%')"
          width="wp('17.5%')"
          onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('Profilee');
          }}></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  else return <></>;
};
```

Navigation:

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Appis"
          component={Appis}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Profilee"
          component={Profile}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Make sure you have this `Home` component as a `Screen` in the navigator.

Comment: I tried what you said but it did not work. I created a new screen Home ad wrote the same code above. Getting the same error.

Comment: Can you show your Stack Navigator ?

Comment: @Dirk Added the stack navigator screen in the question :) I think it requires multiple props

Comment: Where is 'About you' ? It must have the same name, `props.navigation.navigate('Profilee')`

Comment: @Dirk That was already changed before. Still getting the same error thank you